# My navbar toggler arrow not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I made a toggler button with an arrow icon (when menu show) and bars (when menu close), I have made the code as shown below. The problems I am facing are:

1.) When I first clicked the toggler, the 3 bar icons became arrows. But, when I click the toggler button again, it doesn't return to 3 bar icons. So, the toggler is incompatible when it is opened and closed. What should be, when the menu shows, the arrow icon appears and when the menu is closed that appears is the 3 bar icon.

2.) I've coded in CSS for the transitions in arrows, but it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

```js
function toggleMenu() {
    if ($(".navbar-toggler").hasClass("collapsed")) {
        $(".navbar-toggler").removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-toggler").addClass("active");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(){
          toggleMenu();
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar-toggler {
    height: 35px;
  border:none !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-toggler.active .icon-bar {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 35px;
}

.navbar-toggler.active .icon-bar::before {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 15px !important;
    transform: rotate(-35deg);
    top: -5px !important;
    transition: tranform ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggler.active .icon-bar::after {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 15px !important;
    transform: rotate(35deg);
    bottom: -5px !important;
    transition: tranform ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2257A7;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2257A7;
    border-radius: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -12px;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2257A7;
    border-radius: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JQuery you are checking for the "collapsed" class which is unecessary in my eyes as you always hide or show the content when you click the toggler. So you can just switch to the toggleClass() function from Jquery. I changed your code and left a comment where i made the changes. If i understood you right this is what you want it to look like

```js
function toggleMenu() {
// the check for the "collapsed" claass is unecessary, you can simply toggle the class
        $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(){
          toggleMenu();
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar-toggler {
    height: 35px;
  border:none !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-toggler.active .icon-bar {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 35px;
}

.navbar-toggler.active .icon-bar::before {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 15px !important;
    transform: rotate(-35deg);
    top: -5px !important;
    /*you misspelled transform and you need to add a time for the transition*/
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggler.active .icon-bar::after {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 15px !important;
    transform: rotate(35deg);
    bottom: -5px !important;
    /*you misspelled transform and you need to add a time for the transition*/
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2257A7;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2257A7;
    border-radius: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -12px;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #2257A7;
    border-radius: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah Sorry i missed that. Edited my answer with Comment in CSS. You misspelled transform and forgot to give the transition a time, see the Code in my answer for an example. Also i suggest trying "transition: all" instead of "transition: transform", looks a bit more clean to me

Comment: ahh i missed duration and ```tranform``` should be ```transform```, thank you friend